# which is faster? "vector of structs" or "a number of vectors"?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, vector

**Solution 1:**
If i have a class like,

```
class car{ public: int a; string b; bool c;};
```

i can build a vector of 200 cars:

```
std::vector<car>   allcas;  
allcars.resize(200)
```

at runtime, i just do:

```
this_car=allcars[102];
```

then ....

**Solution 2:**

i have

```
std::vector<int> a; a.resize(200);
std::vector<string>b; b.resize(200);
std::vector<bool> c; c.resize(200);

this_car_a = a[102];
this_car_b = b[102];
this_car_c = c[102];
```

Question:
Which one is faster?

Does anyone have an idea? thanks  a  lot in advance!

Comment: Faster for what?  Did you try timing them?

Comment: Benchmark it and see what happens? Unless this is a bottleneck in your code, I suggest you chose the more logical and safer solution (the vector of car classes)

Comment: You'll probably getter better cache usage from `vector<car>` but it really depends on what you are doing with them.

Comment: Can you think of anything more important than speed?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, is a very valid question and actually one I face every day. Designing data structures for optimal memory access on modern processors can increase the performance *significantly*

Comment: @Remus: Indeed.  But the OP has given no information about what he/she intends to do with the data.  So currently, it's impossible to give specific answers.

Comment: What will your access pattern be like?

Comment: with 3 separate vectors, at least you know you are guaranteed contiguous memory, if that is important. with a vector of objects, there can be padding within each vector item, which may or may not matter to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A "struct of vectors" has a couple of advantages over a "vector of structs":

- If your inner loop doesn't use every element of the struct, then struct-of-vectors can save on memory bandwidth, as unused element vectors will not be loaded into cache.
- It is easier to vectorize.  A struct-of-vectors may enable you to use the vector processing instructions of your processor (through assembly, intrinsics, or clever compilers) to speed up your inner loops.

On the other hand, premature optimization is the root of all evil:

- Using a struct-of-vectors is more difficult, awkward, and obscure.
- You generally don't know where your performance bottlenecks are until you've got your code up and running.  Is it worth making your code more verbose, fragile, and difficult?  You won't know until you actually profile it.
- The benefits of struct-of-vectors programming vary on a case by case basis.  It doesn't always yield a speedup; you could actually end up with worse performance.
- In particular, if your access pattern is random (as opposed to sequential or otherwise localized) a struct-of-vectors organization could end up loading much *more* useless data from memory, if each cache line includes elements from multiple nearby objects...

So, my recommendation is to use vector-of-structs by default, but keep struct-of-vectors in mind as an alternative (i.e., make sure you can switch later, if you expect sequential/local access patterns and it doesn't cost much effort up front).  Once your program is running, you can profile it to see where the performance-critical sections are, and try out struct-of-vector and vectorized operations where they'll do the most good.

Comment: See [my comment on Xeo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274268/which-is-faster-vector-of-structs-or-a-number-of-vectors/7274312#7274312) for a real world example of a big win with parallel arrays.

Comment: Another disadvantage of a number of `vector`s is that is it possible for the vectors to have unequal lengths. That is not possible with a `vector` of `struct`s.

Answer (score 15):

If `a`, `b` and `c` belong together and form an *object* together, why the hell would you split them? Go for clarity and readability first. Anything else comes after that. Also, I think v2 would be slower. More access on the vector. Didn't time it though. As always for questions about speed, *time it*.

Comment: SOA (structure of arrays) often makes more sense than AOS when you're doing heavily vectorized operations.  Sometimes, you need to sacrifice clarity when there are huge performance gains to be had.

Comment: @Oli: Of course you're right, there're always special situations. Though, I get the feeling this one's not one of them. ;)

Comment: Amen to that. Unless you had a VERY pressing need for that sort of 'optimization' I would not allow the second example in my code base.

Comment: While this is not a bad general principle, I would like to relate a real world story. CERNLIB (an old particle physics data analysis package) supports two type of "ntuples": rowwise (which were effectively vectors of structs) and columnwise (parallel arrays to use the FORTRAN way of describing these things). In some uses cases choosing a columnwise ntuple could *multiple orders of magnitude* improvements in speed (mostly from disk access issues (this was *a lot* of data for the time)).

Comment: @dmckee: Of course it depends on the access pattern. If the OP had chosen a more sophisticated example, my answer might have been a different one. ;)

Answer (score 12):

CPUs love prefetching.

If you are going to **linearly traverse** your data in the following pattern...

```
abcabcacb...
```

...then you are better off (performance-wise) with solution #1. If you are going to access them as:

```
aaa...bbb..ccc...
```

...then go for solution #2.

**However**, if you are not going to do a linear traversal or if you did not actually benchmark your code and concluded that you really need to squeeze every last drop of performance out of this piece of code, do your maintainability a favor and stick with Solution #1.

**--- EDIT ---**

In a multi-threaded environment, the physical layout of data may lead to [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). Essentially, keeping too close the pieces of data that are **concurrently** accessed by different threads may cause cache contention and destroy the scalability.

So, if you concurrently access `a` from one thread and `b` from another, it may be worth splitting them physically apart and implementing the solution #2. If, on the other hand, you access two "sibling" `a`s, stick with the solution #1.

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

For the excellent treatment of this subject, I warmly recommend Herb Sutter's talk "Things Your Programming Language Never Told You", still available at:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7zSU9HI-6I
 https://nwcpp.org/talks/2007/Machine_Architecture_-_NWCPP.pdf

Comment: I've been wondering, if my access pattern is `abcabcabc...`, then if I have a struct of vectors, will the CPU predict that the next cache line of `a`s, `b`s, and `c`s should be fetched, and once they are fetched, I have more `a`s, `b`s, and `c`s hot in cache, since I have three cache lines hot rather than just one?

Comment: If the CPU notices that the cache lines you have requested so far are sequential, it may start fetching the next one _before_ you have even requested it. That's "prefetching". In the case you describe, the CPU would have to be smart enough to do a kind of a "three way" prefetching. Are today's CPUs smart enough for that? I have no idea. That's why measuring performance is much more reliable than predicting it, especially once you start playing with the memory layout.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, splitting them is a horrible idea for maintainability reasons, which should be your foremost concern.

Second of all, you just tripled your allocation time (three allocations instead of one), deallocation time (same), and destroyed cache locality of reference (probably a slowdown).

Third, The only benefit would be if you only read *one* member for all the cars over and over, and rarely alter the cars.

Comment: I agree with allocation time, and especially the increased chance of cache misses, but deallocation doesn't place your process into waiting, and is an extremely quick operation.

Comment: @Elliott-ReinstateMonica Are you sure? A quick search suggests otherwise. Sometimes deallocation is _slower_ than allocations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030504/why-deallocating-heap-memory-is-much-slower-than-allocating-it

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you want to use your data. For example, if you only want to access one field:

```
car this_car = allcars[12];
cout << this_car.a;
```

Then this causes you to create a copy of this_car. In this case you would be needlessly copying fields b and c. Of course, you can fix this by getting by reference:

```
car & this_car = allcars[12];
```

This is potentially still slower than just doing

```
a = a[12];
```

However, if you want to access multiple properties of your class, then it is almost certainly better to store as them together. At this point you'll probably get better performance because of [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), however it is all really dependent on the compiler, memory manager, etc.

In the end, the answer to which is best performance is: it depends. This will definitely not be a bottleneck decision, and it is definitely better to keep them in a single struct for code readability / your own sanity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the struct members and on your pattern access. One singleton access is irrelevant, but consider you do an iteration over a vector and you're only interested in member `a`. The wider the struct is, the fewer struct entries will fit in a cache line and the more cache misses you'll occur. Moving all `a` members separate in a vector increases the cache line density and thus increases the performance. It can be quite significant (1.5x, 2x, even more).

However, is far more important to focus in code maintainability, make it readable, debuggable and easy to refactor. The code should clearly express the intent. Such micro optimizations as you're asking about should only be considered for *measured* bottlenecks. Get yourself a copy of the [Software Optimization Cookbook](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm).