# speed of (vector of pairs) vs (pair of vectors) C++

Tags: c++, performance, vector, dijkstra

Background:
I have finished writing a game as a homework assignment. where we had to make a game of hex. I decided to implemented the board using a 2d vector of nodes, and used 2 vectors to keep track of x and y coordinates of a node's neighbors. The path finding algorithm i used to determine a winner was similar to that of Dijkstra's.

I realize disadvantage of using 2 vectors is that they would must always be in sync, but i am asking about speed. I also realize that a faster way to implement the board is to probably use a 1d vector (which I realized halfway into finishing the program).

Question: In terms of raw speed, would the path finding algorithm run faster with a 2 vectors to keep track of (x,y) or would the algorithm run faster if I implemented using a vector of pairs?

Comment: This sort of question can best be answered when presented with a small self contained code sample, and by the time you've done that, you're 90% of the way toward building your own benchmark.

Comment: I have done something like this in the past and instead of worrying about pairs as in `(x, y)` I simply converted the pairs into integer `( x * Number_Of_rows + y)` and this is what I used to store each individual position on the board. The neighbors are stored in a similar fashion where each node will store a `std::list<int>` of neighbors

Comment: maybe you like to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274268/which-is-faster-vector-of-structs-or-a-number-of-vectors

Although it's a heavy read, boost docs of their implementation can give much insight about Djikstra specifically: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html

Comment: It is impossible to answer: It depends on the algorithm, amount of data, memory management, ...

Comment: "The path finding algorithm i used to determine a winner was similar to that of Dijkstra's" is not an acceptable description of the code for the purpose of providing an answer that isn't "it depends".

Comment: The main performance issue will be related to cache usage. Using a pair of vectors could result in cache conflicts that wouldn't occur using a vector of pairs.

Comment: I'd say pair of vectors is the faster. You have only 2 vectors and 1 pair = 3 structures. If you use a vector of pairs, you have 1 vector + N pairs, where N is the size of your vector.

Answer (score 5):

**Choose whichever is more suitable for your needs**.
You should not be concerned about performance at this stage of software design.
What is much more important is to choose the data structure you can best work with.

On doing that, the performance benefit is probably already with you.

Comment: He said he already finished it, and after a project is complete and functional seems like the best time to eek out some little performance benefit.  Besides, telling them that they don't need an answer to their question is not an answer.

Comment: Profiling is the best way to optimize, nor guessing or what people call micro-optimizations.

Comment: @user2581799: What might not be obvious from this *answer* is whether the user actually thought of the design upfront or not. From the question it seems that he did not even consider the possibility of a vector of pairs until late in the project. Now aoeu is suggesting to revisit the design: *which data structure can you best work with?* That should be the no. 1 driving force for the design (and I would think a vector of pairs is probably better). You could even say that for this particular case, you should not even consider performance at all (until measured)

Answer (score 4):

aoeu has it right: first worry about nice representation.

Second, if you worry about the game being slow, profile. Find problematic areas and worry about those.

That said, a bit about speed:

Memory access is fastest when it is sequential. Jumping around is bad. Accessing values one after the other is good.

The question of whether a vector of pairs (more generally, vector of structs, VoS) or a pair of vectors (struct of vectors, SoV) is faster depends entirely on your access pattern. Do you access the coordinate pairs together, or do you first process all x and then all y values? The answer will most probably show the faster data layout.

That said, "most probably" means squat. Profile, profile, profile.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me that a vector of pairs would be faster, but you probably need to test it.  Create a test program that inserts a few million points into both formats and time which is faster.  Then time which format is faster to extract stored data.

Answer (score 0):

First, aoeu is on point.

Second, regarding optimization in general:

The first step of optimization is measurement, otherwise you don't have a baseline to compare improvements against.

The next step is to use some sort of profiler to see where your code spend the cycles/memory/other, it might not be where you think.

When you've done those two you can begin to work on optimizing the right parts of your code in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment. If your implementation runs slower as the game progresses ( I'm guessing for the AI part of it), then it is probably because you are running Dijkstra after each move. And as the game gets larger with more moves on the board, the performance of the AI deteriorates.

A suggestion will be to use a `disjoint-set` method rather than `Dijkstra`'s to determine a winner. The advantage of a `disjoint-set` over Dijkstra is that not only does it use less memory, but it does not become slower as the game progresses, so you are able to run it after each player makes a move. [Disjoint-set - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), [Union-find - princeton](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/)

I realize that changing one's implementation of a key part of a project is a daunting task because it requires almost having to `DO IT ALL OVER AGAIN`, but this is just a suggestion and if you are worried about the speed of the AI, then this is definitely worth looking into. There are other there are other methods for implementing an AI such as [minMAX tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), [Alphabeta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning)(This is an improvement to minmax tree)

Gl.